# How to compare two highs in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to find swing low and swing high in the certain past period (numOfCandles that I calculate other way but I didn't want to include that, not important for this question).
I get to a problem that my if statements never get true, and they should be. Its something simple I am missing

```
//@version=4
study("myscript",overlay=true)

// numOfCandles is for example on 1minute chart 480

var HH = high[0]
var LL = low[0]
var HHcandleNum = 0
var LLcandleNum = 0

for i = 1 to numOfCandles
    if high[i] > HH
        HH:=high[i],
        HHcandleNum := i
    if low[i] < LL
        LL:=low[i],
        LLcandleNum := i


var lastLabel1 = label.new(bar_index-numOfCandles,high[numOfCandles],text="")
var lastLabel2 = label.new(bar_index-numOfCandles,high[numOfCandles],text="")
var lastLabel3 = label.new(bar_index-numOfCandles,high[numOfCandles],text="")

if barstate.islast == true
    if label.get_text(lastLabel1)!=""
        label.delete(lastLabel1)
    if label.get_text(lastLabel2)!=""
        label.delete(lastLabel2)
    if label.get_text(lastLabel3)!=""
        label.delete(lastLabel3)
    lastLabel1 := label.new(bar_index-numOfCandles,high[numOfCandles],text="start"),
    lastLabel2 := label.new(bar_index-HHcandleNum,high[HHcandleNum],text="HH"),
    lastLabel3 := label.new(bar_index-LLcandleNum,high[LLcandleNum],text=tostring(low[1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i should have put the calculations inside this if barstate.islast == true... stupid mistake...